¡por qué aparece el error "Nan" al hacer una multiplicación aunque este usando parseInt?
Hola estoy realizando una página que encuentra el área de un Trapecio la fórmula es (B+b/2)+h al principio tuve problemas al sumar B+b por que en lugar de sumarlos se concatenaban entonces el valor del área era incorrecto pero se mostraba en el label. Esto fue por que no había hecho la conversión de string a numero , lo solucione usando parsInt. El problema fue que al hacer eso ya no mostrba el resultado del área sino el error "NaN".
Soy principiante y la verdad entiendo muy poco sobre esto les agradecería mucho su ayuda.
    </head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <img class="logo" src="logofec.png" alt="La imagen no se pudo cargar">
        <b class="otherheader">Finding your area</b>
            Geometría Analítica
    </header>
    <br>
    <div class="main">
        <b class="b">Área de un Trapecio</b>
        <br>
        En este programa se calcula el área de un Trapecio cuya base mayor es denotada por <b>B</b>, su base media por <b>b</b>
        y su altura por <b>h</b>
        <br><br><br>
        <label for="h">Ingrese el valor de <b>h</b>:</label>
        <input type="text" id="h">
        <button class="button" onclick="calcularÁrea()">Calcular Área</button>
        <br><br><br>

        <label for="h">Ingrese el valor de <b>B</b>:</label>
        <input type="text" id="B">
        <button class="button" onclick="calcularaltura()">Calcular la altura</button>
        <br><br><br>

        <label for="h">Ingrese el valor de <b>b</b>:</label>
        <input type="text" id="b">
        <button class="button" onclick="calcularbasemayor()">Calcular la Base mayor</button>
        <br><br><br>

            <div class="rectangulo">
                <img src="rect.png" alt="La imagen no se pudo cargar">
                <div class="Izquierda" id="Izquierda">Izquierda</div>
                <div class="Arriba" id="Arriba">Arriba</div>
                <div class="Abajo" id="Abajo">Abajo</div>
                <div class="Derecha" id="Derecha">Derecha</div>
        </div>
        <br><br><br>

        <label for="h">Ingrese el valor de <b>Área</b>:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Área">
        <button class="button" onclick="calcularbasmenor()">Calcular la base menor</button>

        <br><br><br>
        <button class="button" onclick="Limpiarcampos()">Limpiar campos</button>
        <br><br><br>
    </div>
    <footer class="pie">
        <br>
        Esperamos que te haya sido de ayuda revisa el apartado definiciones de la página principal 
        si quieres saber más del tema.
    </footer>
</body>
<script language='javascript'>
    function calcularÁrea(){
        var mayor = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);
        var menor = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value);
        var altura =parseInt(document.getElementById("h").value);
        var Sumadebases =mayor + menor;
        var division = Sumadebases/2;
        var area = division*h;

        document.getElementById("Arriba").textContent = mayor;
        document.getElementById("Abajo").textContent = menor;
        document.getElementById("Izquierda").textContent = altura;
        document.getElementById("Derecha").textContent =Sumadebases;
        document.getElementById("Área")[0].value=area;
    }
    function calcularbasemayor(){
        var altura = document.getElementById("h").value;
        var area = document.getElementById("Área").value;
        var basem = document.getElementById("b").value;
        var baseM = ((area/altura)*2)-basem;  

        document.getElementById("Arriba").textContent = base;
        document.getElementById("Abajo").textContent = base;
        document.getElementById("Izquierda").textContent = altura;
        document.getElementById("Derecha").textContent = altura;

        document.getElementById("B").value=baseM;
    }
    function calcularbasemenor(){
        var altura = document.getElementById("h").value;
        var area = document.getElementById("Área").value;
        var baseM = document.getElementById("B").value;
        var basem = ((area/altura)*2)-baseM; 
        document.getElementById("Arriba").textContent = base;
        document.getElementById("Abajo").textContent = base;
        document.getElementById("Izquierda").textContent = altura;
        document.getElementById("Derecha").textContent = altura;

        document.getElementById("B").value=basem;
    }
    function calcularaltura(){
        var base = document.getElementById("B").value;
        var area = document.getElementById("Área").value;
        var basem = (area*2)/(baseM-basem); 

        document.getElementById("Arriba").textContent = base;
        document.getElementById("Abajo").textContent = base;
        document.getElementById("Izquierda").textContent = altura;
        document.getElementById("Derecha").textContent = altura;

        document.getElementById("h").value=altura;
    } 
    function Limpiarcampos(){
        document.getElementById("Arriba").textContent = "Arriba";
        document.getElementById("Abajo").textContent = "Abajo";
        document.getElementById("Izquierda").textContent = "Izquierda";
        document.getElementById("Derecha").textContent = "Derecha";
        document.getElementById("Área").value="";
        document.getElementById("h").value="";
        document.getElementById("B").value="";
        document.getElementById("b").value="";
    }
</script>
</html>


¡Saludos y bienvenido a Stackoverflow!
Tu primera función calcularÁrea guarda la altura en la variable altura, pero para calcular el área utiliza la variable h; probablemente esto causa el valor NaN. Otra razón para esto, sería que una de las cajas de texto esté vacía o el usuario haya escrito o pegado un texto (parseInt devuelve NaN en ese caso). Para solucionar este último caso utilizas la funcion isNaN.
Un detalle más: se recomiena no usar var; en su lugar usa const si la variable no va a cambiar luego, o let si el valor puede cambiar. Esto es para evitar que definas la misma variable dos veces por error. Esta sería la primera función con estos cambios; puedes aplicar lo mismo a las otras funciones:
function calcularÁrea(){
    let mayor = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").value);
    let menor = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value);
    let altura =parseInt(document.getElementById("h").value);

    //El input podría estar vacío o tener una letra: 
    if(isNaN(mayor)) mayor = 0;
    if(isNaN(menor)) mayor = 0;
    if(isNaN(altura)) mayor = 0;

    //Esto te permite mirar los valores en la consola: 
    console.log({mayor, menor, altura})

    const Sumadebases = mayor + menor;
    const division = Sumadebases/2;
    const area = division*altura; // Aquí tenías "division*h"

    document.getElementById("Arriba").textContent = mayor;
    document.getElementById("Abajo").textContent = menor;
    document.getElementById("Izquierda").textContent = altura;
    document.getElementById("Derecha").textContent =Sumadebases;
    document.getElementById("Área")[0].value=area;
}


¡Muchas gracias por la bienvenida y por la explicación a detalle! Saludos igualmente. Estoy comenzando aprender sobre la html por mi cuenta y pues aun me cuesta bastante así que aprecio mucho que tomaras el tiempo de explicarme y añadir consejos para mejorar.

Me parece que tu problema de fondo es el desorden en tu código. Si bien tenemos infinitos nombres para asignar a nuestras variables, tendemos a repetirlos. Por eso tienes h y Altura y ahí tienes un error:

h es un elemento HTML que multiplicado por cualquier cosa dará NaN
Una buena medida para mitigar esto es asignar un sufijo a los elementos, así h pasa a ser h_input y de esta manera es más difícil equivocarse.
Por otro lado, tus formulas están mal, el área de un trapecio es ((B + b) / 2) * h, luego las otras fórmulas que derivan de esta también las tienes mal
Aquí una demo, reorganizando el código:


const h_input  = document.getElementById("h"),
      b_input  = document.getElementById("b"),
      B_input  = document.getElementById("B"),
      A_input = document.getElementById("Area");
      
      
const getArea = (B,b,h) => ((B + b) / 2) * h; 
const getBase = (A,b,h) => ((A / h) * 2) - b; 
const getAltura = (A,B,b) => (A * 2) / (B + b);

function calcularÁrea(){
 A_input.value = getArea(B_input.valueAsNumber, b_input.valueAsNumber, h_input.valueAsNumber);
}
function calcularbasemayor() {
   B_input.value = getBase(A_input.valueAsNumber, b_input.valueAsNumber, h_input.valueAsNumber);
}

function calcularbasmenor() {
 b_input.value = getBase(A_input.valueAsNumber, B_input.valueAsNumber, h_input.valueAsNumber);
}

function calcularaltura() {
 h_input.value = getAltura(A_input.valueAsNumber, B_input.valueAsNumber, b_input.valueAsNumber);
}
En este programa se calcula el área de un Trapecio cuya base mayor es denotada por <b>B</b>, su base media por <b>b</b> y su altura por <b>h</b>
<br><br><br>
<label for="h">Ingrese el valor de <b>h</b>:</label>
<input type="number" id="h">
<button class="button" onclick="calcularÁrea()">Calcular Área</button>
<br><br><br>

<label for="B">Ingrese el valor de <b>B</b>:</label>
<input type="number" id="B">
<button class="button" onclick="calcularaltura()">Calcular la altura</button>
<br><br><br>

<label for="b">Ingrese el valor de <b>b</b>:</label>
<input type="number" id="b">
<button class="button" onclick="calcularbasemayor()">Calcular la Base mayor</button>
<br><br><br>


<label for="h">Ingrese el valor de <b>Área</b>:</label>
<input type="number" id="Area">
<button class="button" onclick="calcularbasmenor()">Calcular la base menor</button>




¡Muchísimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder! Me encanto la claridad de tu explicación. Ya solucione el problema. Acataré tu consejo ordaneré mejor los códigos y las variables.

@AidaButtergloss como consejo y que se nota en el código de Yussef, evita usar var y en su lugar usa let y const. Desde hace tiempo que usar var no se considera una buena práctica.
